# react native handle translations and languages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, translation

How do you handle translation in react native? This is how i did it. Is it bad coding style or has it bad performance?

**Language.js**

```
export default {
    appName: "TestApp",
    welcome: {
        header: {
            title: (l) => {
                switch (l) {
                    case "de": return `germanTitle`
                    case "en": return `englishTitle`
                }
            },
            subtitle: (l) => {
                switch (l) {
                    case "de": return `germanSubtitle`
                    case "en": return `englishSubtitle`
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then in my app

```
import language from "./language.js"
let lang = "de"
...

render(){
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{language.welcome.title(lang)}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: I think this question should be in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently in our projects we're using [this repo](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization) :)
Remember that you need to eject if you're using Expo

Comment: what is the advantage?

Comment: i want to have all string on the same place. So when i want to translate something i dont want to scroll

Comment: In your code you're handling the translations via Javascript layer, with the repo you're gonna use the native system for each platform (iOS/Android) which is much better in terms of performance and clean code.

Comment: Also you'll define all the keys and string in one file (or you can split it in one file for each language and import it). But the key point is that all your locales are handled in one entry point and you can call it wherever you want in your application

Comment: mmh... i have all string in one file, too. I just need to import it.

Comment: the problem is in LocalizedStrings is that i can use each key one time. This is very confused if i have many strings.

Comment: It's the normal way of implementing "localizations" in mobile apps, in Android or iOS you can't repeat the same key. They must be unique. And it's useful if you need, for example, to send a file to someone asking for translations in some languages you don't know

Comment: you've convinced me.

Comment: Also, with the repo you're going to detect the device language automatically (via native interaction). With your code you need to pass the language key every time you want to use a localized string, which I don't think it's a good thing.

Comment: but how can i use it in an other component? I get the error cant find variable strings

Comment: should i define strings in every component seperatly?

Comment: I normally use one entry point for all components :) But it's up to you how to handle that. In the READ.ME you can find all the samples for setting it up!

Comment: yes i have one entry Point too. There i have defined strings. In the child Component i should only import LocalizedStrings and then i can use it?

Comment: Yeah, just export your object with all the strings and use it around in the other components :) And thanks for accepting the answer 

Answer (score 0):

Try using I18n. I have used it and customised it to a great extent. It works quite fine and offers more that your app could require in future. I will try to add an example using I18n on git and will comment the link. But for now you can use your own logics.

Answer (score 0):

I made my own solution in [this repo](https://github.com/MeLean/ReactNativeTranslateRedux) by using Redux and AsyncStorage because I had to change language in the app. The implementation is used Expo as CLI, but there is nothing related to Expo. This is an idea to implement, not a ready library ;).

Answer (score 0):

I've created a small library for handling translations in React.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-littera

You can simply add an object with the translations inside your component or import it from a file.

Here is an example using a class component

```js
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";

import { withLittera } from "react-littera";

// Regular JS object with your translations. 
// Can also be placed in another file and just simply imported here.
const translations = {
    title: {
        en_US: "This is a title",
        pl_PL: "To jest tytuł",
        de_DE: "Dies ist ein Titel"
    },
    subtitle: {
        en_US: "This is a subtitle",
        pl_PL: "To jest podtytuł",
        de_DE: "Dies ist ein Untertitel"
    }
};

class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { translated } = this.props; // An object called "translated" is passed with props.

        // This is how you display a translated string.
        return <Text>{translated.title}</Text>;
    }
}

export default withLittera(translation)(ExampleComponent); // <- Here you pass the translations to the withLittera HOC.
```

I've been using the library for quite a few projects and it seems to perform fine. Remember to wrap your app with a **LitteraProvider** and pass it the active language value and a language change callback.

PS. the library is actually for React but it seems to work with React Native without any difference.